# Trying to run Cypher Queries on a simple Neo4j database

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have made a simple structure and i'm having a few problems to query it using Cypher. Given the following structure: http://console.neo4j.org/r/p2xieh

How do i know all of my friends who read books by "Book Author"? How do i know all of my friends who read books by "Book Author" which have a rank higher than 4?

Answer (score 2):

All my friends who read books by "Book Author":

```
start me=node(1) 
match me-[:KNOWS]-friend-[:READ]-book-[:WRITTEN_BY]-author 
where author.name='Book Author' 
return friend.name
```

and all my friends who read books by "Book Author" which have a rank higher than 4

```
start me=node(1) 
match me-[:KNOWS]-friend-[:READ]-book-[:WRITTEN_BY]-author 
where author.name='Book Author' and book.rank? > 4 
return friend.name
```